# pandas : co-occurence matrix with get_dummies

Tags: pandas

I am trying to reshape a dataframe to create a kind of occurrence matrix but without success.

Is `pandas.get_dummies()` the right way to do this at all ?

Here is what I tried so far

```
import pandas as pd 

xlst_entries = [[u'aus', u'fra', u'gbr'],[u'gbr', u'prt'],[u'chn'],[u'bel', u'gbr'],[u'gbr', u'prt'],[u'gbr', u'prt'],[u'gbr', u'prt']]

qq1 = pd.DataFrame(xlst_entries)

qq2 = pd.get_dummies(data= qq1, prefix=None)
qq2
```

But the result I want is

```
index  fra  bel     chn     prt     aus     gbr

 0  1   0   0   0   1   1
 1  0   0   0   1   0   1
 2  0   0   1   0   0   0
 3  0   1   0   0   0   1
 4  0   0   0   1   0   1
 5  0   0   0   1   0   1
 6  0   0   0   1   0   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tweak the parameters inside [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) such that the `prefix` of the columns formed is removed and sum the columns with same name to obtain the desired frame.

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')

df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(np.sum).astype(int)

   aus  bel  chn  fra  gbr  prt
0    1    0    0    1    1    0
1    0    0    0    0    1    1
2    0    0    1    0    0    0
3    0    1    0    0    1    0
4    0    0    0    0    1    1
5    0    0    0    0    1    1
6    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some preprocessing of `xlst_entries` to combine all entries as a single string separated by `|`, then use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
xlst_entries = ['|'.join(x) for x in xlst_entries]
qq1 = pd.Series(xlst_entries).str.get_dummies()
```

The resulting output:

```
   aus  bel  chn  fra  gbr  prt
0    1    0    0    1    1    0
1    0    0    0    0    1    1
2    0    0    1    0    0    0
3    0    1    0    0    1    0
4    0    0    0    0    1    1
5    0    0    0    0    1    1
6    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat general helper function which should work on almost any data.frame (written in python2, for python3 testing, please make sure to wrap the `map` and `reduce` functions with `list`):

```
def get_multiple_dummies(dframe):
    from functools import reduce
    combined = [pd.get_dummies(dframe.iloc[:, i]) for i in range(len(dframe.columns))]
    allcolumns = set(reduce(list.__add__, map(lambda y: y.columns.tolist(), 
        combined)))
    combined = map(lambda x: pd.concat([x, pd.DataFrame(
        columns = filter(lambda y: y not in x.columns, 
        allcolumns))]), combined)
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x.fillna(0)+y.fillna(0), combined)

print get_multiple_dummies(qq1)

   aus  bel  chn  fra  gbr  prt
0    1    0    0    1    1    0
1    0    0    0    0    1    1
2    0    0    1    0    0    0
3    0    1    0    0    1    0
4    0    0    0    0    1    1
5    0    0    0    0    1    1
6    0    0    0    0    1    1

[7 rows x 6 columns]
```